# Replacing triple nodes with values from related statements

Tags: rdf, sparql

Consider the following statements:

```
:id1 :id2 "1942"
:id1 :hasName "Dan"
:id2 :hasName "Born"
:id3 :id4 "50"
```

I would like to have a query that outputs:

```
"Dan" "Born" "1942"
"Dan" :hasName "Dan"
"Born" :hasName "Born"
:id3 :id4 "50"
```

So anywhere it finds that a node from a statement has another statement with ":hasName" predicate, it replaces it with the value from that statement.

Also how could I improve the 
query to output:

```
:id1/Dan :id2/Born "1942"
:id1/Dan :hasName "Dan"
:id2/Born :hasName "Born"
:id3 :id4 "50"
```

Comment: Literals in RDF (e.g., strings) can't be the subject of RDF triples, so while you could have a textual output of `"Dan" "Born" "1942"`, that couldn't be _stored_ in your data.  However, you _can_ generate URIs that incorporate the value of the `:hasName` property.  Note that you'll only want to do this once, though: since you end up with `:id1/Dan :hasName "Dan"` in the results, if you run it again, you'll end up with `:id/Dan/Dan :hasName "Dan"` in the next round, and so on.

Comment: ok, so how can I write a query so that it incorporates the value of the :hasName property in the subject/predicate URI? I don't actually want to store this, I just need it for making it easier to read the results of queries for my particular db schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's easier to work with *complete* datasets, let's provide a prefix for your data so that you have:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/>

:id1 :id2 "1942" ;
     :hasName "Dan" .
:id2 :hasName "Born" ;
     :id4 "50" .
```

Now, it's not clear whether you're trying to *select* a subject, predicate, and object to get the output that you want, or whether you're trying to *construct* a graph.  Let's work with `select` first to get the values that we want, and then we can worry about putting them together into a graph. A query like this one is a good starting point:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/>

select ?s ?p ?o where { 
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

Its results are:

```
----------------------------
| s    | p        | o      |
============================
| :id3 | :id4     | "50"   |
| :id2 | :hasName | "Born" |
| :id1 | :hasName | "Dan"  |
| :id1 | :id2     | "1942" |
----------------------------
```

Now, you want to say that if either `?s` or `?p` has a `:hasName` property (which is optional), then you'd like to use that in the results instead.  You can add a pattern to pull out those names, and then `select` things like `coalesce(?sName,?sx) as ?s` to use the name, if it's available, and `?sx` otherwise:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/>

select (coalesce(?sName,?sx) as ?s)
       (coalesce(?pName,?px) as ?p)
       ?o
where { 
  ?sx ?px ?o
  optional { ?sx :hasName ?sName }
  optional { ?px :hasName ?pName }
}
```

Note that the results can only be called pseudo-RDF, since in RDF, literals (such as strings) can't be subjects of triples, so not all of those values for `?s` could actually be subjects.  If you're manually processing the result set, though, this is fine.  That said, the results are what you asked for at first:

```
------------------------------
| s      | p        | o      |
==============================
| :id3   | :id4     | "50"   |
| "Born" | :hasName | "Born" |
| "Dan"  | :hasName | "Dan"  |
| "Dan"  | "Born"   | "1942" |
------------------------------
```

Now, rather than using the *string* form for `?s` and `?p`, we really want an IRI.  All we need to do is get the string forms of the IRIs with `str`, concatenate them with the name using [`concat`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-concat), and [`IRI`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-iri) to turn the resulting string into an IRI:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/>

select (coalesce(iri(concat(str(?sx),"/",?sName)),?sx) as ?s)
       (coalesce(iri(concat(str(?px),"/",?pName)),?px) as ?p)
       ?o
where { 
  ?sx ?px ?o
  optional { ?sx :hasName ?sName }
  optional { ?px :hasName ?pName }
}
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| s                                                      | p                                                      | o      |
============================================================================================================================
| :id3                                                   | :id4                                                   | "50"   |
| <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/id2/Born> | :hasName                                               | "Born" |
| <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/id1/Dan>  | :hasName                                               | "Dan"  |
| <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/id1/Dan>  | <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/id2/Born> | "1942" |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This form is pretty long, and the IRIs don't appear shortened with the prefix because the `/` can't appear in the name part.  If you use a different separator though (e.g., `-`), you can get shorter looking results:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/>

select (coalesce(iri(concat(str(?sx),"-",?sName)),?sx) as ?s)
       (coalesce(iri(concat(str(?px),"-",?pName)),?px) as ?p)
       ?o
where { 
  ?sx ?px ?o
  optional { ?sx :hasName ?sName }
  optional { ?px :hasName ?pName }
}
```

```
----------------------------------
| s         | p         | o      |
==================================
| :id3      | :id4      | "50"   |
| :id2-Born | :hasName  | "Born" |
| :id1-Dan  | :hasName  | "Dan"  |
| :id1-Dan  | :id2-Born | "1942" |
----------------------------------
```

Finally, if you wanted to get an RDF graph with these triples, you'd probably want to push those `coalesce(… as …)` expressions into the `where` pattern with `bind`.  (You could do this in the earlier example as well, and just do `select ?s ?p ?o`, too.  It's just a matter of taste.)

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/>

construct {
  ?s ?p ?o
} 
where { 
  ?sx ?px ?o
  optional { ?sx :hasName ?sName }
  optional { ?px :hasName ?pName }
  bind(coalesce(iri(concat(str(?sx),"-",?sName)),?sx) as ?s)
  bind(coalesce(iri(concat(str(?px),"-",?pName)),?px) as ?p)
}
```

In Turtle, the result is:

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/> .

:id1-Dan  :hasName  "Dan" ;
          :id2-Born "1942" .

:id3      :id4      "50" .

:id2-Born :hasName  "Born" .
```

In RDF/XML:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/id2-Born">
    <hasName>Born</hasName>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/id3">
    <id4>50</id4>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20299083/1281433/id1-Dan">
    <hasName>Dan</hasName>
    <id2-Born>1942</id2-Born>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```